# Can't compile a C# project, missing NuGet packages but they are installed

Tags: c#

i'm trying to compile a C# project but i can't do it because i get missing NuGet Packages
I did restore the packages and they get installed in the packages folder but i keep getting that error
And all the references have a yellow triangle

[image: yellow triangle]

[image: yellow triangle]

Solution 1 : Tried to restore nuget packages

EDIT 1 : Now i get all this errors, it seems that still can't find those assemblies, and only 4 references are with the yellow triangle (Costura, INIFileparser, Newtonsoft.Json and System.data.sqlite) assemblies
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpr3k.png)

Comment: Check the "Output" tab, and choose to "Show output from: Package Manager". That may show that there were errors when trying to restore the nuget packages.

Comment: Please, post errors as text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the reference with the yellow triangle and then press F4. That is a Visual Studio paths bug. If doesn't work try to clean the entire solution, then restore nuget packages and for each reference press F4.